# Plotting by non-continuous dates - difference with Datetime and Str types of data

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a dataframe with data grouped by date. Important: the dates are not continuous. The sample:
[image]

If I want to plot directly, Python plots with obscure meaning of x-scale.

```
df1[['step_1','step_3']].plot();
```

[image]

If I set dates as indexes, the names on scale become correct - but appear dates which are absent in a source, 2023-09-09 and 2023-09-10.

```
df1[['date','step_1','step_3']].set_index('date').plot()
plt.xticks(rotation=60);
```

[image]

I found out a solution - to change data type in dateframe from `datetime` to `str`. As a result - no additional dates, everything is correct.

```
df1['date'] = df1['date'].astype('str')
df1[['date','step_1','step_3']].set_index('date').plot()
plt.xticks(rotation=60);
```

[image]

The question is: is there any more elegant solution without data type changing?